# Lazarus fpc.cfg is missing

Tags: alien, lazarus

I installed Lazarus with this tutorial http://wiki.freepascal.org/Installing_Lazarus

But when i open Lazarus i get the error:
fpc.cfg missing.

I used the alien command to install Lazaris and this is what i think the mistake(Because the site said: Debian users are recommended to use the deb packages, but may use either alien (warning, it doesn't generate fpc.cfg) or the tarball install.)

How can i create a fpc.cnf file or fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already [stated there](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Installing_Lazarus#Installing_Free_Pascal_from_source_under_Linux.2FBSD) as to how to do that:

1. Open terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type the following:

   ```
   THEPREFIX/lib/fpc/3.0.0/samplecfg $THEPREFIX/lib/fpc/3.0.0 $ETCDIR
   ```

   - Optionally test to see if ppc386 -i (or whatever compiler your architecture uses) gives output, else give a warning that user need to add $PREFIX/bin to his current path. Try to compiler a program with -viwn, and see if that gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use DEB packages anyway. There are DEB files to download directly on official sites. You need to install FPC, FPC-SRC, and Lazarus packages. fpc.cfg is autogenerated in `/etc`.

There is also command from FPC to generate fpc.cfg: `fpcmkcfg`.